# Meta sites for SE2.0 sites open in new window and current window

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta

When I use middle click or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click on the [Visit Meta](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com) link on a Stack Exchange 2.0* site it opens the meta site in the new window *and* the current window.

This is irritating - can it be fixed please?

Note: It works fine for the [meta](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com) link in the toolbar but not for the link in the right hand pane.

*Specifically on WebApps & Programmers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix is on the way. We'll sprite the anchors instead of the H4s. This way we'll get rid of the onclick event on H4s and still have a visible and clickable area. Also in the future, we may look into changing the doctype to html5, where <a> around block level elements are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

This is because HTML 4.01 strict doesn't allow a hyperlink outside a `<div>`, eg, this is invalid markup (but works in every browser just fine..)

```
<a href="">
<div></div>
</a>
```

Putting the link inside the div doesn't work with CSS spriting, and leads to awkward styling problems.

Thus we are forced to use a div with an `onclick` action instead.

```
<div onclick="window.location.href=''">
</div>
```

(similar issue on the homepage and a few other places, anywhere you want an entire div to be a hyperlink..)

Comment: Why do you want the entire div of "Visit Meta" to be a hyperlink?

Comment: @kennytm take a look at any se 2.0 site with the sketchy theme, fex http://diy.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jeff: But WebApps and Programmers do not use Sketchy anymore.

Comment: @Jeff - the `onclick` event isn't attached to a `div` it is attached to `h4` with a hyperlink inside e.g `<h4><a ...> </a></h4>` removing the `onclick` event from the heading makes no difference to styling and the hyperlink works as expected?

Comment: @barry sorry for the confusion, I wasn't clear above, this is a related but slightly different issue. The sprited sites *move the 'inside' hyperlink away somewhere off in hyperspace* (for css spriting) so it cannot be clicked on. The outer container MUST carry the link. Normally I'd say "no problem just wrap the <div> or <h4> in a hyperlink!" but.. no valid 4.01 strict.

Comment: @Jeff - I see now - this makes sense. However as @KennyTM pointed out WebApps & Programmers don't use the sketchy theme any more :) Also, could you not use [this technique explained here by createErrorMsg](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/5857.htm).  I tried it locally on a quick demo page and it appears to work fine.  But I obviously don't have the entire CSS so I don't know what it might affect elsewhere.